# Discordjs fetch members by user tag

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have some user tags like this one `Nickname#1234`, I need to fetch the user with that tag to the bot cache, i've tried [this](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) method:

```
message.channel.guild.members.fetch([options])
```

but it only seems to work with the user ID, it's there a way to fetch the specified member without it's ID?, or get the user ID from a member which isn't in the cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot actually fetch by a user tag because Discord Api doesn't support that yet so you can just fetch all members and find them -

```js
message.channel.guild.members.fetch({cache : false}).then(members=>members.find(member=>member.user.tag === "Nickname#1234"))
```